# html w/php powered pages not displaying; downloadable?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I try to load a php inside an html page, somepage.html ... It brings up a download box.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php html
```

Those were generated in my cpanel but still it shows a download box instead of the code.

What do I do?

Also additional information:

```
Apache version  2.2.17
PHP version     5.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but you can try:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

[Took it from this blog post.](http://www.honeytechblog.com/how-to-fix-applicationx-httpd-php-trouble-in-getting-php-to-parse/)

EDIT: Just saw that you're using PHP inside .html files. Can't you just change the extension?

Comment: I'm doing cookie checks in some html pages I can't change the extension :\ I mean I could but I really don't want to. :|

I just know it's possible I did it on my last host but this one seems different. I really don't know whats wrong. :|